# Laplace transform of product of two functions $f(x)g(x)$ in terms of Laplace transform of $f$ and $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Is there any result which gives Laplace transform of product of two functions $f(x)g(x)$ in terms of Laplace transform of $f$ and $g$?

I think there is no such result for Laplace transform. I was wondering if there is any such result for any other integral transforms like Fourier?

Comment: No. None of the usual transforms behave well w.r.t products.

Comment: Few years back I was in touch with engineering maths and I was trying to develope such type of transform. Today I thought again about it and I think it woupd have good applications to differential equations .  For example, if Laplace transform would had good behaviour with multiplication, we could solve Riccati diff. equation in closed form.

Comment: There are some special cases where the Laplace transform of a product can be computed, for example $\mathcal{L}\{t f(t)\}$

Comment: Yeah but I am looking for general product of functions or at-least for the square of the function.